# Formula to calculate standard error using 95% confidence interval

Tags: r, standards, confidence-interval

I have a column containing 95% confidence intervals as shown below. I would like to calculate standard error using the formula SE = (upper limit – lower limit)/3.92 in R studio.

I would like to know how to calculate SE when the upper limit and lower limit are in the same as shown below:

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Note that you are making very strong assumptions with this (i.e., the confidence limits are quantiles of a normal distribution). These assumptions can be violated easily. Confidence intervals don't even need to be symmetric around the estimate.

Comment: Yes, as @Roland commented, could you please describe a little bit background on your model and what these CI are for. We don't want future readers to blindly apply your formula.

Answer (score 1):

You want to first separate lower bound and upper bound into two columns.

```
interval <- c("(0.023, 0.031)", "(-0.031, -0.022)")
lim <- do.call("rbind", stringr::str_extract_all(interval, "[+-]?[0-9\\.]+"))
mode(lim) <- "numeric"
lim
#       [,1]   [,2]
#[1,]  0.023  0.031
#[2,] -0.031 -0.022
```

Then you can use your formula:

```
(lim[, 2] - lim[, 1]) / 3.92
#[1] 0.002040816 0.002295918
```

---

**Note for others:** 3.96 = 1.96 * 2, and 1.96 is `-qnorm(0.025)`.

Comment: typo in note: 3.92 not 3.96. Will fix it in the next revision.